# Gitolite repositories management

Tags: git, gitolite, repository

I am new to Gitolite and getting hard time on managing repos in it. We have 1000+ repositories in our git server and 200+ users. It look so messy when we run ssh git@hostname, it gives me the drop down list of those repositories With write access and read access both.

Also when i want to clone 'y' repo, i run the command;
git clone git@hostname:x/y

but if want to clone folder 'z' under 'y'
git clone git@hostname:x/y/z ----it gives me following error

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/123456/z/.git/
R access for x/y/z DENIED to vb-ubuntu-32
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I don't want to keep creating separate repos under the same folder like for 'z'.

Is there any way that i can clone only the content of the repo?

My repo list is getting huge with the same multiple repos like below
x/y
x/y/z
x/y/f
x/y/f/g

i dont know if my gitolite setting is not configured correctly.

Thank you for your support in advance.

Comment: Subfolders in git repos are not separate repos and can not be treated as such. Maybe have a look at submodules?

Comment: Was there something missing for you to unselect the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The main gitolite feature which is close to what you are looking for is called **[namespaces](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/namespaces.html)**:

> In many projects, developers need to push their work to some central place for others to fetch.
>   Namespaces allow you to give each developer what looks like her own repo or set of repos, while combining all these logical repos into one physical repo on the server. This saves a lot of disk space if they all share a lot of common history.

It combines namespace-like path for the repo (`x/y/z`) with less repos on the server.
(read its documentation carefully though)

But even then, `y` cannot be a repo, as [Chronial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758345/chronial) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472992/gitolite-repositories-management#comment23637174_16472992).

---

> I wonder if there is way to clone the folder or files from the git server (using gitolite) inside the particular repo. Like `x/y` and `z` is folder inside `y`.
>   How to clone `z` only for that repository?

You can clone a repo within another (nested repos), but the official way to do that is to use **[`git submodules`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**

Comment: Thanks Von.. but i am not much worries about the space or repositories in the server. I wonder if there is way to clone the folder or files from the git server (using gitolite) inside the particular repo. Like x/y and z is folder inside y. How to clone z only for that repository? I do 'git clone git@host-name:x/y/z' but it doesnt work. I have to do git clone git@host-name:x/y. That i have to clone the whole files/folder in that repository.

Comment: @sam you can clone a repo within another (nested repos), but the official way to do that is to use git submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules